# Prevent firebase emulator closing on finishing the tests

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

I am running my firebase tests using the following command

```
firebase emulators:exec --ui 'mocha --reporter spec --timeout 10000'
```

but the ui closes and emulators shut down as soon as the test finishes. I have looked at the params in the help but cant seem to find a way to keep them running so I can check values in the db.

I have tried starting the emulators first and then running with exec but it always complains that emulator instances are already running.

Is there a method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try starting the firebase emulators:start and then running your test script after it has started

```
mocha --reporter spec --timeout 10000
```

It fails when you run exec after starting because the ports assigned to the emulators are busy.. Instead of running exec after the emulators have started, run the test script itself